# Mongo aggregation framework on big data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

Could you please help me with mongoDB aggregation. Here is what I would like to do next:

I have collection `A`. A document from `A` represents an object like:

```
{
  nameA: 'first',
  items: [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4'
  ]
}
```

And I have the Collection `B` with documents like:

```
[
    {
      item: 'item3',
      info: 'info1'
    },
    {
      item: 'item3',
      info: 'info2'
    },
    {
      item: 'item3',
      info: 'info3'
    }
]
```

I work with big data, so it would be better to do it in one query. Imagine that we already have all data from collection A. I would like to build a query on collection B to get next structure result:

```
{
    'first'/*nameA*/: ['info1', 'info2', 'info3'],
    ....
}
```

How do I achieve the desired result with MongoDB aggregation?

Comment: This is not very helpful design, note that Mongo doesn't allow joins, there is $lookup to manipulate like left join, you can check out the documentation for $lookup in aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul Kumar mentioned in his comment, your design is more leaning towards a relational database schema design, and it makes it quite difficult to design efficient MongoDB it.

However, it is still possible to achieve the functionality you are looking for by leveraging the `$lookup` stage of the aggregation framework, as follows:

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$items"
        }
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: "B",
            localField: "items",
            foreignField: "item",
            as: "item_info"
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$item_info"
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$nameA",
            item_info: { $addToSet: "$item_info.info" }
        }
    }
]);
```

1. In the first `$unwind` stage you normalize the `items` array on
   `collection A` in order to be able to pass its output to the next
   stage
2. In the `$lookup` stage you make a left join between two collections
       that are part of the same database, in this case used to get the
       item information from `collection B`
3. In the second `$unwind` stage you normalize the data you extracted
       from `collection B` in order to flatten the array containing the
       objects from `collection B` that were mapped to the corresponding
       items in `collection A`
4. Finally, in the `$group` stage you group all the entries of the
       result set by `nameA` and create an array of unique item information
       values. If you would like to have all the duplicate occurrences of
       the item information values, you can replace the `$addToSet`
       accumulator with `$push`.

Below is the result of running the above aggregation pipeline on the collections that you provided:

```
{ "_id" : "second", "item_info" : [ "info3", "info2", "info1" ] }
{ "_id" : "first", "item_info" : [ "info3", "info2", "info1" ] }
```

Comment: Yep :) I understand it would be better to use relational database schema design, but it is already written. Really appreciate your help! Thank you very much!